# JSF : Generated java source - how to view?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

To get a better understanding of how JSF works, I would like to take a look at the java source code generated for a `.xhtml` file (for example `home.xhtml` by the JSF container.  Could someone let me know how to instruct the JSF container to retain the java source file generated for `home.xhtml` file?

I am assuming that similar to a JSP getting converted to a java source file before it is run in a JSP container, a JSF file also would get converted to a java source file before it is put to use by a JSF container.

I am using Tomcat 7 and Mojarra 2.1.6.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Wrong assumption. It is interpreted (and cached), nothing is generated to java and compiled. For other differences between jsp and facelets, use google

Comment: JSF generates HTML / CSS / JavaScript based on the component tree and sends that hypertext as a response to the associated client. Unlike JSP, it is not converted to a Servlet.